# mac terminal freezed. Which command should I use to go back to main terminal?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

AS I run the Javascript file, mac terminal ended up showing the error. Is there any command to get back to last terminal option?

[image: mac terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press "Ctrl + C" keys to exit the program